# How to Automatically insert decimal in Input field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I am using a Angular directive that formats input fields numbers with commas. I would also like this filter to automatically insert the decimal for cents.Every number will always have cents involved. For example if I wanted to put $1,000.00 in a input field i would have to type 100000. I made a plunkr but cant get the angular working

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HyEwZrwDTODbRkUusjtO?p=preview)

```
app.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        if (!ctrl) return;


        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
            return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
        });


        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
            elem.val($filter('number')(plainNumber));
            return plainNumber;
        });
    }
};
 }]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably like this?

```
ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
    var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+]/g, ''); //replace even dot and comma
    elem.val($filter('number')(plainNumber/100 , 2)); //use number filter with 2 decimal places and divide the number by 100
    return plainNumber;
});
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iFnjcq?p=preview)**